# input erasing data when having related renderUI

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

In one tab I have an add/remove button to add/remove elements with inputs
In other tab I have an amount of inputs according to the previous tab.
But when I make a modification in the first tab, any input on the second one is erased.
How can I avoid this?

```
#output 1
example <- reactiveValues(var1=rep("",15), var2=rep("",15))

output$tab1 <- renderUI({
n <- counter$n #adding or removing elements
lapply(seq_len(n),function(i){ 

textInput(inputId = paste0("var1_", i), label = paste0("label_", i), 
value = example$var1[i])
})
#output 2 in a separate file
output$tab2 <- renderUI({
n <- counter$n #adding or removing elements
lapply(seq_len(n),function(i){ 

textInput(inputId = paste0("var2_", i), label = paste0("label2_", i), 
value = example$var2[i])
})
```

More concrete: If I have two variables under a reactivevalue, and each one is filled in different menuitem under an input. why one's info is erased when I modified the other in its menuitem? and how to avoid that?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Like where is `counter` coming from?